# First network in hyperledger

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I am trying to work on my first network in Hyperledger Fabric. Using the following documentation
http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_network.html

I have completed the setup till 
http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_network.html#create-join-channel

but when I run the

```
peer channel create -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c $CHANNEL_NAME -f ./channel-artifacts/channel.tx --tls $CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem
```

I got error as

> **Error: Got unexpected status: BAD_REQUEST**

Searching for the issue i came across
http://hyperledgerdocs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/asset_trouble.html

Hence I've tried to use a new channel name as given(old channel name=mychannel), 
I've tried below cmds

`CORE_PEER_COMMITTER_LEDGER_ORDERER=orderer:7050 peer channel create -c myc1`

`CORE_PEER_COMMITTER_LEDGER_ORDERER=orderer.example.com:7050 peer channel create -c myc1`

`CORE_PEER_COMMITTER_LEDGER_ORDERER=172.18.0.2:7050 peer channel create -c myc1`

For all the three I am getting error

> **Error: Ordering service endpoint  is not valid or missing
>   Usage:
>     peer channel create [flags]**

Also I've tried to skip it assuming the channel is already created.
hence ran

```
peer channel join -b ./mychannel.block
```

But got

> **Error: proposal failed (err: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = chaincode error (status: 500, message: Cannot create ledger from genesis block, due to LedgerID already exists))**

My OS is Ubuntu 16.04

docker ps 
[image: Docker ps output]
Kindly help

Comment: Did you try running the out of the box version first to make sure everything is setup correctly:


`./byfn.sh -m down`
`./byfn.sh -m generate`
`./byfn.sh -m up`


If this works, then we can try to debug further.  If it does not work, it should help provide a clue as to what the issue may be

Comment: Yes i tried it and it was working... but then i started running the individual commands and got this error.

Comment: Output for out of the box version

https://pastebin.com/76nDaA6u

Comment: You might want to run `./byfn.sh -m down` again to clean up everything?

Comment: ran the `./byfn.sh -m down`
it stopped and removed all the containers
but still getting same error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's try to make sure you run thru all the steps as outlined in [docs](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_network.html).

1. First of all you need to edit your `docker-compose-cli.yaml` file the *cli* section to comment out line responsible to run automatic flow of channel creation and join:

   ```
   command: /bin/bash -c './scripts/script.sh ${CHANNEL_NAME}; sleep $TIMEOUT'
   ```

E.g.

```
# command: /bin/bash -c './scripts/script.sh ${CHANNEL_NAME}; sleep $TIMEOUT'
```

2. Next export channel name you are working with:

   `export CHANNEL_NAME=mychannel`
3. Start the network (use default timeout of 60s):

   `CHANNEL_NAME=$CHANNEL_NAME docker-compose -f docker-compose-cli.yaml up -d`
4. Enter the cli container:

   `docker exec -it cli bash`
5. Export environmental variables:

   `export CHANNEL_NAME=mychannel`
6. Create the channel:

   ```
   peer channel create -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c $CHANNEL_NAME -f ./channel-artifacts/channel.tx --tls $CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem
   ```
7. Join the channel:

   ```
   peer channel join -b mychannel.block
   ```

Comment: Sorry i missed the
# command: /bin/bash -c './scripts/script.sh ${CHANNEL_NAME}; sleep $TIMEOUT'
 hence the error

Comment: No worries, I realized that is the case after read your question second time and saw the " Error: proposal failed (err: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = chaincode error (status: 500, message: Cannot create ledger from genesis block, due to LedgerID already exists))" error message.

Comment: I'm navigating through this tutorial too and came across this really useful answer! I've ran through these steps and in step 6, I'm seeing the following error - I'd appreciate any help I can get in resolving it!.....

Error: got unexpected status: BAD_REQUEST -- error authorizing update: error validating ReadSet: readset expected key [Group]  /Channel/Application at version 0, but got version 1